# Overloading Operators

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iterator, operators, operator-overloading

I am currently attempting to overload the ++ operator on the .begin() for my square list contatiner.

My in my hpp file I have the following:

```
template <typename T_>
    class sq_list 
    {

    public:
        typedef T_* iterator;

        iterator _itr;
        square_list( iterator n ) : _itr(n) { }


    sq_list operator ++ (sq_list<int> lhs) {    
        return  lhs++;
        }
    };
```

Currently this requires me to put the iterator inside of the square list object.
What I need it to do is to call the ++ method when the .cpp file does a ++name.begin(); instead of putting that value inside of my container and then incrementing that container.
How do I get my overloaded function to work just on the ++name.begin() to increment my iterator instead of having to put it inside my sq_list container?

Thanks!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore how do i get my ++operator to just work on the iterator itself instead of putting it into my square list object

Comment: why does your `operator++` take two `sq_list` parameters  (the implicit `this` and `lhs`)?  From what I understand you want to overload `operator++` for your iterator (which you aren't doing with that code btw). Since `iterator` is a pointer why yould you need to overload the operator? Pointers already has an`operator++`

Comment: @Grizzly whats the implicit this? I take the lhs as my var to take the iterator

Comment: @Grizzly I'm overloading the ++ operator on my customized container that I created (the square list) therefore the default ++ operator shouldn't work I think.

Comment: Your `operator++` is a (non static) member function. As such it takes the `this` pointer as a hidden parameter. Have you tried to compile your code? It won't, since your `operator++` doesn't get correct arguments. You made it sound like you wanted to overload `operator++` for your iterator (which is of type `T_*`, so you can't overload it's operators). Maybe you should clarify what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: The iterator is an object of itself. Why would you declare an operator on an object anywhere else but the object declaration?

Comment: I'm sorry, but "overload the ++ operator on the .begin() for my square list contatiner" just doesn't make any sense, no matter which way you spin it. Could you please write the question more tidily?

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry, what I guess i mean is to reinvent the wheel and just get the operator function to work when i increment the iterator if that makes any sense. I realize that i was wrong originally saying .begin()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you need to define the operator on the iterator. Here, your iterator is a pointer to the underlying element type, so ++ already works on that. Have you tried calling ++ simply on the iterator, without an `operator++` implementation at all?